# Could not find support-core-ui.aar Ionic 3 build error

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle, ionic3

I have been unable to build my Ionic 3 app and keep receiving the following error every time I run `ionic cordova build android`.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
 A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
 > Could not find support-core-ui.aar (com.android.support:support-core- 
ui:27.1.1). 

BUILD FAILED

 Searched in the following locations:
  https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-core- 
 ui/27.1.1/support-core-ui-27.1.1.aar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -- 
debug option to get more log output.
Total time: 17.493 secs
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not find support-core-ui.aar (com.android.support:support-core- 
ui:27.1.1).
Searched in the following locations:
  https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-core- 
ui/27.1.1/support-core-ui-27.1.1.aar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -- 
debug option to get more log output.
```

I have built the app before and I don't understand why it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by mooving `google()` to the top in

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    ....
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont see any `google()`. I instead see                                           ` `maven { url "https://maven.google.com"}`